# Emacs/ESS - Moving through iESS Buffer very slow

Tags: emacs, ess

Moving within the iESS[R] buffer is painfully slow - I use Alt+p/Alt+n or Ctrl+p/Ctrl+n for this purpose.
I do see a 'help' being displayed in the minibuffer when I try to traverse the iESS[R] buffer. Not sure if this the cause for slowness - Can it be disabled?

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  grid      utils     stats     graphics  grDevices methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
 [1] bootstrap_1.0-22 lattice_0.19-26  xtable_1.5-6     stringr_0.4
 [5] ggplot2_0.8.9    proto_0.3-9.2    reshape_0.8.4    plyr_1.5.2
 [9] nlme_3.1-101     MASS_7.3-13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] RColorBrewer_1.0-2 digest_0.4.2       tools_2.14.0
```

Comment: how big is the buffer? Are you on a remote? To disable eldoc (help) just do M-x eldoc-mode and see if it helps. But it should not affect the speed at all. eldoc in ess is very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer is around 500K lines as it contains work ouput over few days. I am logged into a server machine and am not sure about the access speed of the files being read by eldoc.

Either way, this fixed it for me

```
(setq ess-use-eldoc nil)
```

Manual says the following should work too, but haven't had luck with that yet

```
(setq ess-use-eldoc ’script-only)
```

VitoshKa, thanks for the response

Comment: Ok, that explains it. This has been fixed in ESS for some time. What version of ESS are you using. I think in ESS[12.09] this is already fixed. The new version should come out pretty soon. After upgrade, you can use eldoc again.

Comment: I am using ess-12.09 actually